# How to structure my timeseries mongodb document and entries

Tags: database, mongodb, data-structures

I will be storing some OHLCV (open, high, low, close, volume) data for bunch of digital assets inside a MongoDB database.

These are the properties of the each entry that will go into the db:

First, there will be 5 timeframes.

- '5m' for data that increments every 5 minutes.
- '15m' for data that is incremented every 15 minutes.
- '1h' for data that is incremented every 1 hour.
- '4h' for data that is incremented every 4 hours.
- '1d' for data that is incremented every 1 day.

For that, I thought it would be a good idea to put each of those records in their separate collections, so I have 5 collections: `myassetdb.5m`, `myassetdb.15m`, `myassetdb.1h`, `myassetdb.4h`, `myassetdb.1d`

Is that a good idea?

Then each document entry is designed in the following way:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f084269ef9c1e67f3bc8671"
    },
    "asset": "BTC/EUR",
    "timeframe": "5m",
    "stream": {
        "timestamp": {
            "$timestamp": {
                "t": 1,
                "i": 1594377598
            }
        },
        "open": {
            "$numberDecimal": "8417.5"
        },
        "high": {
            "$numberDecimal": "8418.5"
        },
        "low": {
            "$numberDecimal": "8401.2"
        },
        "close": {
            "$numberDecimal": "8411.5"
        },
        "volume": {
            "$numberDecimal": "14.69836761"
        }
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2020-07-10T10:39:58+00:00"
    }
}
```

What matters here is the `asset name` the `timeframe` and the `stream`. It is important that later I can keep adding entries with the most recent data based on the time. And in general, it will be a structure similar to a CSV kind of a process. Where things look like the following

```
timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume,pair,timeframe
1592479800,8407.6,8409,8407.6,8409,9.07373197,BTC/EUR,5m
1592480100,8409,8411.3,8408.7,8410.3,7.2545515,BTC/EUR,5m
1592480400,8410.4,8410.4,8403.2,8405.9,12.64222715,BTC/EUR,5m
1592480700,8405.9,8406,8394.2,8403.1,7.87145576,BTC/EUR,5m
```

So I can add new entries as the data flows

```
timestamp,open,high,low,close,volume,pair,timeframe
1592479200,8417.5,8418.5,8401.2,8411.5,14.69836761,BTC/EUR,5m
1592479500,8411.5,8411.7,8407.6,8407.6,3.79545517,BTC/EUR,5m
(new data above this line)..................................
1592479800,8407.6,8409,8407.6,8409,9.07373197,BTC/EUR,5m
1592480100,8409,8411.3,8408.7,8410.3,7.2545515,BTC/EUR,5m
1592480400,8410.4,8410.4,8403.2,8405.9,12.64222715,BTC/EUR,5m
1592480700,8405.9,8406,8394.2,8403.1,7.87145576,BTC/EUR,5m
```

Don't get me wrong, I included the CSV example here just to demonstrate my data needs. I just need to be able to access and update based on the `date`, the `asset` and the `timeframe`

Is my data structure suitable for this kind of db workflow? The whole thing looks like the image below.

[image]

Just for clarification, I'm adding this section. Do I need some kind of nesting, or is it ok for the data to be flat, as for example in the image below:

[image]

Comment: if you don't have to read the data together. I don't see an issue here.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. What do you mean by 'read the data together'? Do you see any need for optimisation here? For example, putting the OHLCV values in a list? Such as `data:[8409,8411.3,8408.7,8410.3,7.2545515]` or do I need to create a nested hierarchy, like I have it here, all OHLCV values are children of `stream`? or should I have it all flat?